# Isn't $\gamma_{n,g}=0$ if $g>n-3$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\gamma_{n,g}$ the number of ways of putting down x $y's$ on the intervall $[0,n-1]$ with the $y's$ separated by at least two $z's$ and let $\gamma_n=\sum_{g=0}^{n}\gamma_{n,g}$.

Maybe a stupid question, but isn't

$$
\gamma_n=\begin{cases}\gamma_{n,0}, & \text{ if }1\leq n\leq 3\\\sum_{g=0}^{n-2}\gamma_{n,g}, & \text{ if }n\geq 4\end{cases}
$$

So why summing up to $g=n$?

Comment: Where is the $g$ coming from?

Comment: ups, sorry g=x, i.e. the number of y's

Comment: Are your $x,y,z$ some numbers or just some symbols?

Comment: any symbols-- doesnt matter

Comment: I think the only $n$ for which we really have to sum from $g=0$ to $g=n$ is $n=1$...

Comment: If that is the case, then it seems to me that there are uncountably infinite ways of doing this arrangement unless $n=1$ in which case you have no way of doing this. How is $n$ playing a role here? Can you explain your logic? Maybe I am missing something. Are you saying the interval $[0,n-1]$ or the set $\{0,\cdots,n-1\}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22951/discussion-between-math12-and-samrat-mukhopadhyay).

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Is $\gamma_{n,g+1}\leq\gamma_{n,g}$?

Comment: If $g=\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor$, then, $\gamma_{n,g}=1,\ \gamma_{n,g+1}=0$. Now, if $g<\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor$, then the approach to answer this question should be to first consider some arrangement of the $g$ y's in interval $[0,n-1]$ and then try to place another $y$ at some place such that the z' distance between the y's are maintained.